# Django - How to put a html folder into django templates

Tags: python, html, django

I have my website built using django framework. Now we know django is a MVC based framework. And now I have a html folder which contains html file generated by doxygen. There are many .html files inside the folder and link each file via "`<a>`" tag and have image(.png) inside the folder too. I know that django has to set urls to all html pages and put it into templates and also put the image into static file and collect it via "manage.py collectstatics". Is it any easier way to embed the whole html folder into my django project?

Comment: Your generated html pages are static files too, they should be stored in staticfiles along with the images and served the same way.

Comment: The common way to serve a html folder is using a web server such as nginx or apache. Official document also mention [this][https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/].